# How to ensure code runs every time a view is called - Django

Tags: django

With respect to Django generic Views, how do you get a function to run every time a view is called?
For example, when I do:

```
class infoRequestPage(CreateView):
    model = InfoRequest
    form_class = moreInfoForm
    template_name = 'info_request.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('HomePageView')

    pageVisit = InfoRequest(
        infoName = autoName,
        infoRegion= autoRegion,)
    pageVisit.save()

    print("test")
```

It will return `test` as expected, but only the first time I load the page.However, if I update the source code and change the print command to something different like `"testing"`, it will run again. But like last time, only the first time the page loads.
I have tried to clear the cache, and restart browser, but both do nothing. It seems to run only once until the code is changed.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? theres multiple approaches but they all revolve around the django request lifecycle

Comment: When a user visits my page I want to store some values in my database like the region they are from, the time they visited, etc. So I thought I would do this in the view. During testing, it only seemed to run once, even though I refreshed the page, so I suppose I am just trying to understand how this works, and why it only runs once.

Comment: It once once because it is part of the classes instantiation nothing to do with who or what calls it.  You need to look into middleware or what functions are called inside the view, research into GDPR wiill also be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this on get do

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
   print("test")
   return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
```

and on post

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
   print("test")
   return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: There's a copy-paste error in `def post` - should be `super().post(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [**`dispatch(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch):

```
class infoRequestPage(CreateView):
    model = InfoRequest
    form_class = moreInfoForm
    template_name = 'info_request.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('HomePageView')

    pageVisit = InfoRequest(
        infoName = autoName,
        infoRegion= autoRegion,)
    pageVisit.save()

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('test')
        super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

For example the [**`LogoutView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutView) uses this to ensure that it logs out a user before it redirects, or renders a page, regardless whether it is a GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH, etc. request:

> ```
> class LogoutView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, TemplateView):
>     """
>     Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
>     """
>     next_page = None
>     redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
>     template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'
>     extra_context = None
>
>     @method_decorator(never_cache)
>     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         auth_logout(request)
>         next_page = self.get_next_page()
>         if next_page:
>             # Redirect to this page until the session has been cleared.
>             return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)
>         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
>     # ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks @willem Van Onsem, this works also. Do you see any issues using `def get` as @HenryM provided above compared to `def dispatch`?

Comment: @mattG `dispatch` is invoked whenever the view is invoked. `get` is invoked only  for an HTTP GET, `post` only for an HTTP POST.